# Record audio in a safari browser using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, ipad

I was searching for some solution to record audio inside of the browser and send for a webservice. I have found some solutions, but they only work for Chrome or Firefox. So, I wanna know:

Is there someway to record audio in SAFARI?

PS: I don't wanna use the tag **video**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the getUserMedia API from WebRTC to access the user's microphone without any plugins. You can check out what browsers currently support the webrtc functionalities here: http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/
At the moment it is not ready for safari.
The best support for webrtc is given by google because they are pushing this standard a lot.